# $P,Q$ are Hermitian operators with only non-negative eigenvalues, then tr($PQ$) = 0 $\implies$ that $PQ = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

So far I can prove:

suppose there is a basis set $\{|i>\}$ that diagonalize $P$ with eigenvalue $p_i$, then tr($PQ$) = $\sum_i<i|PQ|i>$ = $\sum_ip_i<i|Q|i>$.

Since $P, Q$ are Hermitian with non-negative eigenvalues, both $p_i$ and $<i|Q|i>$ is non-negative...

Now there are at least two possibilities to make tr() = $0$.

i) all $p_i$ = $0$, then of course $PQ = 0$

ii) all $<i|Q|i>$ = $0$, then I can't prove $PQ = 0$...

iii) $p_i$, $<i|Q|i>$ alternates to be $0$, $PQ$ = ???

I think they should be a very easy problem... But I am just stuck somehow..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here.

Comment: Try to use square roots $\sqrt{P}, \sqrt{Q}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly direct argument.

You have 
$$
0=\operatorname{tr}(PQ)=\operatorname{tr}(P^{1/2}P^{1/2}Q)=\operatorname{tr}(P^{1/2}QP^{1/2}). 
$$
As $Q\geq0$, you have $P^{1/2}QP^{1/2}=P^{1/2}Q(P^{1/2})^*\geq0$. And the trace is faithful, so $P^{1/2}QP^{1/2}=0$. Then 
$$
0=P^{1/2}QP^{1/2}=P^{1/2}Q^{1/2}Q^{1/2}P^{1/2}=(Q^{1/2}P^{1/2})^*Q^{1/2}P^{1/2}=0.
$$
So $Q^{1/2}P^{1/2}=0$. Now multiply by $Q^{1/2}$ on the left and by $P^{1/2}$ on the right.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Two points I don't understand. i) $Q ≥ 0$, does it mean every entry of $Q$ matrix $≥ 0$? ii) what does 'trace is faithful' mean and why that implies $\sqrt{P}Q\sqrt{P}$ = $0$. I'm a physics student, I am not quite familiar with linear algebra.

Comment: "Nonnegative entries" is not a property of an operator; when talking about operators, "positive" means "positive semi-definite". That the trace is faithful means that it is injective on positive operators; this is an easy consequence of the fact that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.